# Is it possible to have LSP support VB.net?

Tags: linux, vb.net, language-server-protocol

For roslyn seemed to support LSP, and is available under linux, is is possible to have LSP support in Visual Studio code, or Kate?
If yes, how?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Previous threads on GitHub still apply, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/25 and https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/1111 so possibility is never a question, but nobody seriously ever attempted to make it a reality.